# Calling swapCursor using a CustomCursor for GIngerbread

Tags: android, cursor, android-support-library, custom-adapter, android-cursorloader

I am using a custom adapter that extends CursorAdapter along with a CursorLoader and a Fragment,I made sure to use everything from the v4 library...however the method swapCursor in my adapter does not seem to work below HoneyComb.

How can I implement the equivalent of this code for Gingerbread:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}
@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: it has to work. What error did you get?

Comment: Eclipse shows me an error claiming that my swapCursor method needs the new API...found the solution my custom adapter extended android.widget.CursorAdapter instead of the equivalent adapter in v4 support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was a simple mistake.

I was extending `android.widget.CursorAdapter` instead of `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter`.